# error on php composer.phar install

Tags: php, debian, rabbitmq, composer-php, autoload

I m new to php and rabbitmq.In Debian I have installed composer.phar in /bin direcoty. Now I want to run below command to fetch the defined dependencies for local project.

```
php composer.phar install
```

But it throws an error message using red background as below

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL  
   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                       
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify   
  failed                                                                       
  Failed to enable crypto                                                      
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Please help what to do ? 
    when enable openSSL in php.ini it throws below warning

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable openssl otherwise you can't make a ssl connection.

You can do that in your php.ini if its already installed. Otherwise you have to install it first.

Perhaps as another solution install the php5-cli version with openssl and don't use the lampp stack. You can install the command with `apt-get install php5-cli php5-openssl`. Then you should use the internal package and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am using Debian.

Comment: I did as you suggested and rerun the command and I found below warning:Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You use debian with lampp???? Why?? You have one of the best repositories in on that planet. Why you don't install PHP from that? Thats much easier. `apt-get install php5-openssl` and normally that is installed by default.

Comment: I have posted another solution.